# ASP.NET Core MVC 2.1.0 session is not working after publishing in IIS-10

Tags: c#, session, asp.net-core-mvc, iis-10

I want to keep some values in Session as I can access those values in application. It is working fine on localhost. But when I tried to access remotely/from server after publishing, it is not worked. the session value is null.

I am using .NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1 with "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "2.1.1".

HomeController.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
        {
            HttpContext.Session.SetObjectAsJson("key", "Test value");           
            return View();
        }
    public IActionResult About()
        {          
            ViewBag.SessionValue = 
                 HttpContext.Session..GetObjectFromJson<String>("key");
            return View();
        }
}
```

About.cshtml:

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "About";
}
<body>
  Value:    @ViewBag.SessionValue
</body>
```

Here during running from Visual Studio 2017 it shows in About page
Expected Result:

```
Value: Test Value
```

But after publishing in windows server 2016 IIS 10.0, it shows in About page
Actual Result:

```
Value:
```

Comment: Try to set the variable in About action and see what happens.

Answer (score 4):

You should write `options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => false;`
in `ConfigureServices`.

```
services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
{
    options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true; // consent required
    options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
});
```

Then add `AddSession` before the `AddMvc`. 
Additionally, to mark the cookie as essential, set IsEssential to true.

```
    services.AddSession(opts => 
    {
        opts.Cookie.IsEssential = true; // make the session cookie Essential
    });

    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
```